# Internet slow down after 2-5 minutes Win7 x64 Realtek PCIe FE 8167

Tags: windows-7, networking, bandwidth

I am at my wits end here.  I have been fighting this issue for about a few months now with no end in sight.

I purchased a new HP Pavilion 17-e180nr with a Realtek PCIe FE 8167 NIC that came with Windows 8.  As I love Win7, have a 1tb HDD from my old HP, didnt feel like spending the next year trying to reinstall everything and get updates with my blazing fast internet, instead of using Win 8 i just swapped the HDD with my old one and re-registered my Win7 to this PC.

The issue is when I first go online, everything is fine but after about 2-5 minutes, my throughput drops way down and never recovers.  This was not an issue with my old laptop, and I would not have bought a new one if it wasn’t for the fact that my old laptop got damaged in a way that is probably unique to my location.

– system specs:
HP Pavilion 17-e180nr with a Realtek PCIe FE 8167 NIC
2.5GHz up to 3.5GHz AMD Elite Quad-Core A10-5750M Accelerated Processor 
4MB L2 Cache
8GB DDR3L SDRAM (1 DIMM)
AMD Radeon HD 8650G graphics with up to 4206MB total graphics memory
1TB 5400RPM hard drive with HP ProtectSmart Hard Drive Protection
10/100BASE-T Ethernet LAN (RJ-45 connector)
1x1 802.11b/g/n WLAN

Background 
– I am using Freedom Sat internet – I am in Afghanistan – I am one of those damn dirty contractors you hear about :-)

– I am an IT guy from way back and this issue is making me feel real stupid

– issue happens if I am using Firefox, IE or Chrome

– issue happens whether or not I am downloading anything or just surfing

– issue only happens to my computer (being the IT guy I monitor the bandwidth usage of the Freedom Sat and while others are pulling a blazing RX rate of 3500Kbps (yes 3500Kbps) I am pulling 500Kbps or less

– If I open only one program, let’s say iTunes and start a download, I get 4500-5000Kbps for about 2-5 minutes then it starts to drop

– same thing if I only open FF and start a download, I know what you’re thinking, but even if it is a work related download the same thing happens

– if I disable and re-enable my NIC the issue starts over with good speeds ( I know you are laughing by now at my “good” speeds of 5000Kbps) and then slows down

– I have tried every driver I can find for this NIC and even some older drivers that may not be specifically for this NIC but work

– I have tried many different adjustments in the advanced setting of the driver such as flow control enable/disable, speed and duplex to 100 full instead of auto and many many other settings to no avail

– I have run many different scans to make sure I don’t have virus or malware or anything (seeing how this has been happening as soon as I got the computer and put my old hard drive in this POS – I doubted it was any of those since it worked fine in my old laptop) (spybot, Malwarebytes, AdwCleaner, JRT, ESET and MSE and all came back pretty clean.  I know its hard to believe but yes, they came back pretty clean with only a few minor things that were not rated as dangerous in the least or unwated, but I still let the tools have their way with the files and remove the files and reg keys (in total all tools removed around 10-12 of these files, reg keys).

– I monitor my throughput using the MS provided resource monitor (somewhat accurate) as well as the Realtek Ethernet Diagnostic utility (pretty accurate) and the monitoring station that I monitor everyone’s bandwidth and throughput from Freedom Sat

Anything else you all need to help me with this, I will be happy to supply.

Thanks in advance for any help you all can offer.

Sincerely,
Bewildered and perplexed in Trashcanistan

Comment: I had the same problem long time ago, my internet was right until 20 min or so, problem was the router.

Comment: Mind telling me what you had to do to fix the router?  the only thing here is that several other people use the same internet and router and i monitor them all and their throughput is just fine.

Comment: Turn your router off for around 24 hours. Could be a virus. Reinstall.

Comment: Even factory reset it.

Comment: Thank you.  I know its not a virus.  my computer is clean and have run many different tools to make sure.  as for the router, there are others that use this same internet and router and their connections are just fine and cant really factory reset it or shut it down as it will take them down as well and since they are working just fine, i am starting to believe that it is less the router and something else going on.  i have replaced the switch in between my computer and router as well as all the cables and still same issue.  thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so… I have an update and a fix, but not sure why it fixed the issue.

I ordered and received a USB 10/100/1000 NIC and set it up and uninstalled my onboard NIC drivers and removed all files only to have the same issue thus ruling out the hardware.  Started doing more digging and noticed a program I had overlooked in the past.  AMD Quick Stream.  So I researched the program and it is a legit program, however, I didn’t like what it did as it sounded like it could possibly be causing my issue just by reading the description of how it works.  I uninstalled it and bingo, a blazing fast 2500-3000 Kbps sustained for over an hour straight while running multiple downloads, Skype, Facebook and a game or two while using the 10/100/1000 USB NIC.

I disabled the USB NIC and reinstalled everything for my onboard NIC and happy to report I am still good to go.

Has anyone else ever heard of the AMD Quick Stream causing issues like this?

Thanks for all the views and assistance offered.

Sincerely, 
NuckinFutz

Answer (score -1):

you cant swap hdd from one system to anothertic system(computer) without driver problems,etc.resolution problejms, network problems, especially going to 8 from 7; i hady rosimilar issues. best to step down fro 8 to 7 on your new drive with microsoft; they will allow you to go down from 8 to 7. dont just stick in an old hdd betteron yet, clone your 8 hdd to an sdd cheers

Comment: Ummm... you sure you're posting for the right question?  This answer has nothing to do with the question.